# Error running MongoDb on MacOSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, homebrew

I am trying to run mongo with rails i get the following Error

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.1
connecting to: test
2014-06-14T12:07:46.356+0530 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2014-06-14T12:07:46.357+0530 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

When i try to repair MongoDB

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:nomad harshamv$ mongod --repair
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5504 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Harshas-MacBook-Pro.local
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] 
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.1
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Wed Apr  2 23:52:02 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.92.1~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] options: { repair: true }
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2014-06-14T11:06:52.964+0530 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

This is the Error i get when i am trying to run my Rails app

```
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure in VenuesController#index
Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:70100620147140 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="127.0.0.1:27017">]>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error `Unable to create/open lock file` can be caused by these three things:

1. MongoDB process is running and is un-responsive
2. Your previous MongoDB process didn't shutdown cleanly.
3. You don't have write permissions on that folder / file.

> Case 1:

You need to check if `mongod` process is active. In your terminal console, enter:

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

If you can see a process you can kill it with:

`kill $(pidof mongod)`

or `kill -2 $(pidof mongod)`

Use `-9` option only as a last resort.

You will also need to remove the old `mongod.lock` file and then start `mongod`.

> Case 2:

If there wasn't an active process, then MongoDB didn't shut down cleanly.

You just need to remove `mongod.lock` file and then then start `mongod`.

> Case 3:

If you removed the mongod.lock file and you're getting the same error, you should check the permissions on your `dbpath` folder (`/data/db/`). This can happen if you started mongod with `sudo`.

Your user or mongod should be the owner of the folder. You can change it with:

```
chown -R $(id -u) /data/db
```

Answer (score 2):

Another process/instance of mongodb is running in background, so terminate it first. Even if no such process is running, you need to go to where your mongodb data directory is and clear the content in a file that has the end extension in its name `.lock` (mongod.lock). Only then you will be able to run mongodb properly.

Steps to terminate a process:

1. Browse to the location `/Applications/Utilities` and double click on 'Terminal'.
2. Run `ps aux | grep mongo`.
3. Then run `kill -9 <PROCESS-ID>` for process number you get in the first line (I believe there would be two lines in total unless more processes with similar names are running. )

Comment: how to terminate the process? bcos i am not able to enter mongo and get into mondogb terminal as well.